# Comparison of subspace topology with product topology of two order topologies

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Problem:** Let $(X, <)$ and $(Y, <)$ be $2$ simple ordered sets, and $\tau_{X, ord}$ (resp. $\tau_{Y, ord}$) the corresponding order topologies. let $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$.

We equip $X \times Y$ with the dictionary order coming from the two given orders. We can now view $A \times B$ as a subspace of $(X \times Y, \tau_{dict})$, or as a productspace of two order topologies.

Are both topologies on $A \times B$ comparable, in general?

**Attempt:** I think they are not comparable in general. I was trying to find an open set in $A \times B$ (for the subspace topology) which is not open in the productspace, and vice versa.

The opens in $(X, <)$ are of the form $(a,b), [a_0, b) $ (if $a_0$ is the smallest element) and $(a, b_0]$ (if $b_0$ is the largest element of $X$), and similarly for $Y$. This collection forms a basis.

The open sets in $A \times B$ for the subspace topology are then found by intersecting $A \times B$ with the opens from $X \times Y$. I started with taking $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ and considering $(x \times x, x \times y]$. I was trying to figure out if this is open in $A \times B$ for the subspace topology, and not open in the productspace topology. If I would draw this in the $(X,Y)$ plane, this would be like a vertical half-open interval, extending from the point $x$ upwards. I need to show that $(x \times x, x \times y]$ is the intersection of $A \times B$ with an open in $X \times Y$.

I think I have to consider different cases here, i.e. whether $A, B$ have smallest or largest elements? Still I don't know how to handle this problem, since $A$ and $B$ are some abstract subsets of $X$ and $Y$ and so I don't know how they look like.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you just want to show that in general the two topologies aren't comparable, it suffices to give an example where the topologies are incomparable. $A = B = X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ works.

Comment: Ah I see. What about taking $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ and $A = B= [0,1]$. Then I would take $(\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \times 1].$ This is open in subspace topology, but not for productspace topology? What would be an example of the converse?

Comment: Grrmblff. I got myself confused. It doesn't work, and it can't work. I'll write an answer explaining it.

Comment: There is a bit of subtlety in the statement of the question: when you talk about the "product of the two order topologies", do you mean the order topologies on $A$ and $B$, or their subspace topologies with respect to the order topologies on $X$ and $Y$?  Those may not be the same.  (And if you mean the latter, there is no need to mention $A$ and $B$ at all, since you might as well just consider the case $A=X$ and $B=Y$.)

Answer (score 1):

For $X=Y=A=B=[0,1]$, the two topologies are incomparable.  First, the set $\{0\}\times (0,1)$ is open in the dictionary order topology (it is the open interval $(0\times 0,0\times 1)$), but is not open in the product topology.  On the other hand, the set $[0,1]\times[0,1/2)$ is open in the product topology.  However, it is not open in the dictionary order topology, since it contains no open interval around the point $1/2\times 0$ (since the left endpoint of such an interval would be $s\times t$ for some $s<1/2$, and then $u\times 1$ would be in the interval for any $u$ such that $s<u<1/2$).

Comment: I don't quite understand why $[0, 1] \times [0, 1/2)$ is not open in the dictionary order topology. If I draw this: it is a vertical half-open interval beginning at the point $1/2$ on the $y$-axis and extending upwards to the point $1$? We need to show that it cannot be intersection of an open in $X \times Y$ with $A \times B$.

Comment: If I intersect $A \times B$ with the open set $(0 \times \frac{1}{2}, 0 \times 2)$ (open in the dictionary order), then I get your set? Hence it is open for the subspace topology?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see you had taken $X = Y = [0,1]$. I thought you were working with $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why it is a contradiction if $u \times 1$ would be in  the interval for any $u$ such that $s <u< 1/2$? Please explain...

Comment: @user454229: Such a point $u\times 1$ is not in $[0,1]\times[0,1/2)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Is it because $1 \not\in [0, 1/2)$?

Comment: @user454229: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The subspace topology $\tau_{sub}$ on $A \times B$ induced by the dictionary order is always finer than the product topology $\tau_{A\times B}$ if $\tau_{dict}$ is finer than the product topology $\tau_{X\times Y}$ on $X\times Y$. For then, the inclusion

$$(A\times B, \tau_{sub}) \hookrightarrow (X\times Y, \tau_{dict}) \to (X\times Y, \tau_{X\times Y})$$

is continuous, and $\tau_{A\times B}$ is the subspace topology induced by $\tau_{X\times Y}$ on $A\times B$, so by definition the coarsest topology for which the inclusion is continuous.

$\tau_{X\times Y} \subseteq \tau_{dict}$ happens for example if no open set in $Y$ - I assume the dictionary order is $(x_1, y_1) \leqslant (x_2,y_2) \iff \bigl((x_1 < x_2) \lor ((x_1 = x_2) \land (y_1 \leqslant y_2))\bigr)$, if your convention is the other one, switch the roles of $X$ and $Y$ - contains a largest or smallest element. For then every open $V\subset Y$ is the union of open intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ with $a_i,b_i \in Y$, and hence

$$\{x\} \times V = \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigl((x,a_i), (x,b_i)\bigr)$$

is open in $\tau_{dict}$, so

$$U \times V = \bigcup_{x\in U} \{x\} \times V \in \tau_{dict}$$

for $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$. Since every set in $\tau_{X\times Y}$ is the union of open rectangles, it follows that $\tau_{dict}$ is finer than the product topology.

But if there is an open $V \subset Y$ that contains a largest element $s$ (but no smallest element), and $s$ is not the largest element of $Y$, then $s$ has a successor $s'$, i.e. $s < s'$ and $(s,s') = \varnothing$, so we can replace any $(a_i,s]$ occurring in the representation of $V$ as a union of open intervals with $(a_i, s')$, and the argument above shows that $\{x\}\times V$ is open in $\tau_{dict}$. The same holds for smallest elements in an open set that aren't the smallest element of $Y$. So $\tau_{X\times Y} \subseteq \tau_{dict}$ [and consequently $\tau_{A\times B} \subseteq \tau_{sub}$] whenever $Y$ has neither a largest nor a smallest element.

But when $Y$ has a largest element, it is possible that $\tau_{dict}$ and $\tau_{X\times Y}$ are incomparable. Let for example $X = [0,+\infty)$ and $Y = [0,1]$, both endowed with the usual order inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\tau_{X\times Y}$ is the standard topology, so the set

$$W = \{ (x,y) : x < y\}$$

is open in the product topology. But $W$ contains no dictionary-order neighbourhood of e.g. the point $(1/2,1)$, for every such neighbourhood contains points $(1/2+\varepsilon, 0)$ with $\varepsilon > 0$. Thus $W \notin \tau_{dict}$. And

$$O = \{ (x,y) : (x,y) < (3,1/2)\}$$

is open in $\tau_{dict}$, but not in $\tau_{X\times Y}$ since no Euclidean neighbourhood of $(3,1/4)$ is contained in $O$.

Thus we have incomparable topologies $\tau_{X\times Y}$ and $\tau_{dict}$.